# Interfaces in blackberry10

Tags: blackberry-10

I am new to blackberry 10 platform and I am developing an application that is already in java. In the Java application there I used many interfaces for usability. I don't know how to use this interfaces in Blackberry 10. Please give me some samples using interface in blackberry 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a lot of discussion of this topic in previous StackOverflow questions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492741/java-no-interface-implementation).

As one of the responders says a C++ class with only pure virtual methods is the same thing as a Java interface. C++ allows multiple inheritance, which has its own pitfalls if used incorrectly. Inheriting from one or more classes with only pure virtual methods is the equivalent of implementing one or more interfaces.

It sounds like you are not familiar with C++. You need to tool up your skills. C++ is not the same language as Java. Especially under Cascades or Qt you need to be aware of who is responsible for freeing memory (deleting objects) and when. Java will forgive many sins, C++ will not forgive any.